# Java HTTP-Server implementation can't send images correctly

Tags: java, image, http, header

I am implementing my own HTTP server using sockets. In my java project folder I have a folder /root where all the files are saved which can be downloaded (test.html, test.jpg), so when the user browses to let's say localhost:8080/test.html my server takes the file, reads it and sends the bytes to the client's browser ,setting the right headers. Everything works fine with the .html extension but I have a problem with the images...the browser says that the file cannot be shown properly.
Here is the class which I use to read the bytes from the file:

```
 public class FileRequestHandler {

public FileRequestHandler(){

}

/*
 * Method which reads a text-file and turns it into a string
 */
public String readFile(String file) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (file));
    String         line = null;
    StringBuilder  stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String         ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    try {
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append(ls);
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
 }

}
```

after executing readFile() I get a string(I will call it response).

Now I set the headers and send them to the client:

```
    out.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    out.println("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    out.println("Content-Length: " + response.length());
    out.println();
    out.println(response);
    out.flush();
```

out is a PrintWriter object. 
As I already mentioned, this method works with a html-file and everything is shown. What am I doing wrong? Maybe the encoding of the raw-bytes is incorrect or the headers were set incorrectly?
Thank you for the help!

Comment: So you're using the same method for processing text files and binary files (images)?

Comment: You should not use `println()`. The line terminator in HTTP is defined as `\r\n`, not as whatever `println()` gives you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An image is not a text file.  Yet you are apparently reading it as text using a `BufferedReader`.  That will mangle it ... and the use of `readLine()` and the line reassembly mangles it some more.

Either way, the browser will be unable to decode the mangled image that your server is sending.

You should use InputStream / OutputStream subtypes rather than Reader / Writer subtypes, and you should NOT attempt to convert the image into a string at any point.

(It is also a bad idea to attempt to implement an HTTP server using socket-level I/O ... but that's a different issue.)

Comment: ok, but if I cannot convert it to String , how could I for example directly encode the image as a base64 string?

Comment: @Teo Why? Just write the bytes to the output.

Comment: Why would you want to encode it as a base64 string?  Your content type says "image/jpeg" and doesn't specify an encoding.  If you sent a base64 encoded body, that would be mangled too.

Comment: @EJP how to write the bytes to the output? Can I still use the PrintWriter object?

Comment: @Teo That's not what it says in my answer.

Comment: @Teo - You can't use `PrintWriter`.  You need to use an OutputStream subtype.  (Surely, you know how to write bytes to a stream.  If not, there are numerous tutorials, examples, etc that explain how.  Ask Mr Google.)

Comment: @Stephen how to attach the headers after that which are of type String?Do I just have to convert the String to byte?

Comment: Yes.  (Or better still, use a proper server-side HTTP library instead of doing the low level stuff yourself.  There are all sorts of risks with implementing the HTTP stack yourself.  For instance, you may miss out important parts of the HTTP spec and end up with a non-compliant implementation.)

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (file));
```

The problem starts here. Readers and Writers are for text. Images are not text. You should be using an input stream, and writing bytes directly to an output stream, not collecting them in a String.